Angular 18 SSR Standalone - Routes to be generated from data before Bootstrap
I can't figure out how to make this work without using shady magic wizards incentations so, I might be missing something.
My case example:
I have a Angular 18 SSR simple app with route home and user/:username
I dont want to query my database from my website so I need to get all my users beforhand and generate routes accordingly
If I receive this users data:
  { name: 'alice', email: 'alice@example.com' },
  { name: 'bob', email: 'bob@example.com' },
  { name: 'charlie', email: 'charlie@example.com' },

I want to have Angular SSR to generate my website with routes:

user/alice
user/bob
user/charlie

I tried adding them dynamically like this
 addUserRoutes(users: any[]) {
    const newRoutes = users.map(user => ({
      path: 'user/' + user.name,
      component: UserComponent,
      resolve: { user: user },
     }));
   this.router.resetConfig([...this.router.config, ...newRoutes]);
 }

If I print my router.config I got all the routes I wanted but ofc SSR didnt generated them so I can't find them on my website which is why this solution is not working
I tried getting the data before bootstrap
export function initializeApp(http: HttpClient) {
  return (): Promise<any> =>
    firstValueFrom(
      http
        .get('generated/db-data.json')
        .pipe(
          map((data: any) => data.users),
    ));
}

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideAngularSvgIcon(),
    provideHttpClient(),
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeApp,
      multi: true,
      deps: [HttpClient],
    },
  ]
};

But then I dont know how to use those users to update my routes array in my provideRouter(routes).
I am going to try to just use the data from initializeApp directly to create my routes array dynamically and try to use it directly updated in provideRouter(routes).
EDIT: I discusses with my coworkers and as it is, my database is actually a big json that I will stop doing async calls and deal with dependency injections etc and just
import userData from '../../public/generated/db-data.json';


 function generateRoutes(): Routes {
  const userRoutes = userData.users.map(user => ({
    path: 'user/' + user.name,
    component: UserComponent,
    data: { user },
  }));

  return [
    ...userRoutes,
  ];


What if the user details are changed by the users, without API call to backend how will you know if it has changed, isn't dynamic routes like /user/:username the best solution for you!

No, if data has changed we can redeploy, the website needs to be SSO optimized so static everywhere I can, this is my use case for now but I agree with you, If I wanted to have user profiles updated often i would use an external API

The best solution is to use Prerendering parameterized routes where you specify which routes you want to prerender, then SSR, renders these routes as static routes, and there won't be unnecessary API calls to fetch the users in frontend.
You first need to configure a parameterized route like user/:username or something like that.
Then you can write a script that generates the routes.txt from an API call which gets the list of users from DB, then when you build the application, the routes.txt is processed and you will get the desired result.
This script will be processed by the angular application before running npm run start or npm run build
...
"start": "node dynamic-routes.js && ng serve",
"build": "node dynamic-routes.js && ng build",
...


Oh my, I completely dodge this documentation part ..... Thanks
But now I am wondering how to give all my user data to the route
The documentation is ok to define a route but I also want the route to have my entire user object as data
Maybe something like
/products/1?name=charlie&email=toto@toto.com
/products/555?name=marie&email=toto@toto.com

@TheSegfault Yes, you can make an API call on ngOnInit which fetches the data, then angular SSR, will prerender the HTML using this API call and populate the HTML, so that HTML can see all the data during web crawling

Great thanks, SSR is smart enough to use what he finds on the ngOnInit of each route and do the call, this is amazing !
